# Libgdx sprite size matching screen size

Tags: java, libgdx, size, screen, scaling

---

So i have a created a background which is 1920 x 1080 in size.

And i have a window that is 1280 x 720 (will not always be this size)

Now when i render the sprite using this code:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) 
{
    Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(0.2F, 0.5F, 1F, 1F);

    Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    sb.begin();

    sb.draw(Assets.splash_spr_bg, 0, 0);

    sb.end();
}
```

The sprite appears in the window but not the whole sprite, just like 1/2 of it.

Now here's my question:

·How can i make the sprite fill the whole screen no matter what size the screen is?

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: Are you the same person as Dumbostyle? The answer is the same as the one I put on their question: use a Viewport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using Viewports for this: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

Its a great way to handel screen sizes.
To make it fill the whole screen u probably have to try something like:

```
Picture1.setX(stage.getWidth() / 2 - Picture1.getWidth() / 2); 
Picture1.setY(stage.gethight() - Picture1.getHeight() /)
```

In this example i use a stage, but it will work without just remember that u get the screen width and height instead or set them to 0,0 and place it under in the corner. Also notice that i cut the width in half, this is because it will otherwise always render outside your screen. Then u could try and use something like:

```
Picture1.setSize(stage.getWidth() / 2, stage.getHeight()):
```

the other way u could do it is by setting your viewport zoomed in on the picture (so the same size) that way it will also give you a full screen view even tho i dislike that idea, but thats a personal preference. Also this later one wont make your background look all stretched and pixelated because it isn't being resized, but if u take a picture thats big enough you also wont notice it in the first option.

Just mess around a little with it, its pretty easy.

Example of how to implement Viewport: http://pastebin.com/3SrWKcEg

Comment: Thanks! These are the answers i need when i ask questions, thank you so much! :)